# Can I convert matplotlib.AxesSubplot object to JSON?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a histogram chart from a DataFrame object. For this I used `df.hist(bins=3)` which returns `matplotlib.AxesSubplot`.

With this output, how can I convert it to JavaScript JSON object to send it to HTML page to generate a chart from it.

Comment: Unless your HTML page is able to process python code, you would save the figure to png and display it as image.

Comment: I was imagining that if I can send that data as JSON to the HTML, I can use javascript to parse the data and plot the graph. Is this process possible? Can we achieve this?

Comment: If you want to use javascript to create the graph, you wouldn't need to create a graph with matplotlib first, just send your data in json format.

Comment: [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) is a python plotting library that does basically what you are describing.